# Как сделать, чтобы текст был справа от картинки?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать, чтобы текст был справа от картинки на экранах <768px?

html код:

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <a href=""><div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><img class="img-responsive" src="images/11.jpg" alt="">
            <p>The Arecaceae are a botanical family of perennial climbers, shrubs, acaules and trees commonly known as palm trees</p></div></a>
            <a href=""><div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><img class="img-responsive" src="images/22.jpg" alt="">
            <p>Palms are among the best known and most extensively cultivated plant families. They have been important to humans throughout much of history.</p></div></a>
            <a href=""><div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><img class="img-responsive" src="images/33.jpg" alt="">
            <p>Many common products and foods are derived from palms, and palms are also widely used in landscaping, making them one of the most economically important plants.</p></div></a>
            <a href=""><div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><img class="img-responsive" src="images/44.jpg" alt="">
            <p>In many historical cultures, palms were symbols for such ideas as victory, peace, and fertility. For inhabitants of cooler climates today, palms symbolize the tropics and vacations.</p></div></a>
            <a href=""><div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><img class="img-responsive" src="images/55.jpg" alt="">
            <p>Whether as shrubs, trees, or vines, palms have two methods of growth: solitary or clustered. The common representation is that of a solitary shoot ending in a crown of leaves.</p></div></a>
            <a href=""><div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><img class="img-responsive" src="images/66.jpg" alt="">
            <p>Most palms grow in the tropics and subtropics. They are abundant throughout the tropics and subtropics, and thrive in almost every habitat they are in. Their diversity is highest in wet, lowland forests, especially in ecological "hotspots" such as Madagascar, which has more endemic palms than all of Africa.</p></div></a>
            <a href=""><div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><img class="img-responsive" src="images/77.jpg" alt="">
            <p>Subfamily Calamoideae includes the climbing palms, such as rattans. The leaves are usually pinnate; derived characters (synapomorphies) include spines on various organs, organs specialized for climbing, an extension of the main stem of the leaf-bearing reflexed spines, and overlapping scales covering the fruit and ovary.</p></div></a>
            <a href=""><div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><img class="img-responsive" src="images/88.jpg" alt="">
            <p>This monopodial character may be exhibited by prostrate, trunkless, and trunk-forming members.</p></div></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Использовать float: left?

Comment: применимо к тегу <p>? Пробовал, почему-то не получилось.

Comment: #content p {
 float: right;
} - добавил в css, ничего не изменилось

Comment: Как я понимаю, надо ссылки сделать float: left;  Тогда текст будет справа от них.. А так у вас параграф располагается ниже ссылок.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Первый вариант. Надо положить картинку и текст в один блок 1, картинке задать, например, `float:left`. Потом еще надо создать пустой блок 2 внутри блока 1 (или `clearfix - ::after`), задать блоку 2 свойство `clear:left`.
2. Второй вариант. Положить картинку и текст в один блок 1, блоку 1 задать `position:relative`, картинке задать `position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px;` ,текст положить в параграф, параграфу задать `margin-left`, равный ширине картинки

Answer (score -1):

Лучше всего всё переписать под нормальную блочную верстку с `css display "table"`:

```
<style>
.container {
  display:table;
} 
.row { 
  display:table-row;
} 
.cell { 
  display:table-cell;
} 
</style>
<div id="content">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">               
         <a href="...link1..."><img src="... img1 ..."></a>
      </div>
      <div class="cell ...">
        <a href="...link1...">Текст 1</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- остальные строки - div class="row" -->
  </div>
</div>
```

А то блоки и параграфы в ссылке... включайте музыку поспокойнее  когда программируете :-)

P.S. В HTML 4.01 ваша конструкция с блоками и параграфами внутри ссылки вообще не будет работать, в HTML 5 будет, но это знаете - как если бы выступить на научной конференции на блатном жаргоне... скорее всего поймут о чем речь, но... :-)

Comment: Если же хотите, чтобы на блок срабатывал переход по ссылке (не только непосредственно на картинке или тексте) - нужно тогда поставить блоку .row стиль cursor:pointer, а блоку добавать onclick через javascript window.location = ... Но так неправильно с точки зрения SEO. Но можно и так и так одновременно кстати

Comment: >> Блочная верстка >> display: table. Чё?

Comment: @VostokSisters, ато! блочная это когда <div> (div это блок), табличная это когда <table> (table это таблица)

Comment: Ну так и верстал бы table, tr, td. Разницы бы не было совершенно. 0. Ты сделал верстку таблицами через классы с дисплеем: table.  Привет, динозавры.

Comment: @VostokSisters, это блочная верстка, еще раз говорю. табличная - это когда table, и если вам она нравится - применяйте, я же разберусь без вас как мне лучше... Блочная верстка в табличном стиле появилась намного позже табличной, как рекомендуемая альтернатива. Табличная верстка для layout не рекомендуется, поскольку тормозит больше и не рекомендуется SEO (поговаривают что поисковики списывают ранг если много таблиц на странице).

Answer (score -1):

Переписать разметку - здравая тема. Но можно сделать вот так:

```
a img {
  float: left;
}
```

Тогда будет по спеке все - обтекание текста вокруг картинки, ради этого float и был придуман когда-то.