# Текст переносится под картинку

Tags: html, css

Если текста больше, чем вмещается в 1 строку, то он переносится на картинку (скрин прилагаю)[[image: Скрин1]

```css
.lenta1 {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  diplay: block;
}

.text {
  width: 60%;
  font-size: 15px;
  position: relative;
  font-weight: bold;
  white-space: normal;
}

@media (max-width:768px) {
  .text {
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 10px;
  }
  .leftimg {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
  }
  .rightimg {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
  }
}

h5 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
  position: ablosute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  float: left;
}

h6 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: ablosute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  float: left;
  font-weight: bold;
}


}
.leftimg {
  float: left;
  /* Выравнивание по левому краю */
  
  margin: 10px 20px 10px 0;
  /* Отступы вокруг картинки */
}
.rightimg {
  float: right;
  /* Выравнивание по правому краю  */
  
  margin: 10px 0 20px 10px;
  /* Отступы вокруг картинки */
}
```

```html
<div class="lenta1">
  <br />
  <h5 style="font-weight:bold;">29.10.2009</h5>
  <br />
  <br />
  <h5 align="left" style="font-weight:bold;">ВЫСТАВКА "POSTPRINT - 2007" ТОРГОВАЯ ВЫСТАВКА КНИГОПЕЧАТАНИЯ</h5>
  <br />
  <br />
  <div class="text">
    <img src="/images/baba1.png" alt="ВЫСТАВКА " POSTPRINT - 2007 " ТОРГОВАЯ ВЫСТАВКА КНИГОПЕЧАТАНИЯ" width="20%" height="25%" class="leftimg"> Торговая выставка книгопечатания.</div>

</div>
<div class="lenta1">

  <br />

  <h6>29.10.2009</h6>
  <br />
  <br />
  <h6 align="left">РОССИЙСКИЕ ПИСАТЕЛИ ВОШЛИ В СПИСОК МОЛОДЫХ ЛИТЕРАТУРНЫХ ТАЛАНТОВ США</h6>
  <br />
  <br />
  <div class="text">
    <img src="/images/baba2.png" alt="РОССИЙСКИЕ ПИСАТЕЛИ ВОШЛИ В СПИСОК МОЛОДЫХ ЛИТЕРАТУРНЫХ ТАЛАНТОВ США" width="20%" height="25%" class="rightimg"> Авторитетный в англоязычном литературном мире британский журнал Сгама составил новый перечень наиболее
    многообещающих молодых писателей США. В него вошли и писатели русского происхождения.</div>

</div>
<div class="lenta1">

  <br />
  <h5 style="font-weight:bold;">29.10.2009</h5>
  <br />
  <br />
  <h5 align="left" style="font-weight:bold;">ВЫСТАВКА КНИГИ РОССИИ</h5>
  <br />
  <br />
  <div class="text"> <img src="/images/baba3.png" alt="ВЫСТАВКА КНИГИ РОССИИ" width="20%" height="25%" class="leftimg">Традиционный весенний форум отечественных книжников - Национальная выставка-ярмарка «Книги России» проходит на территории Всероссийского выставочного центра
    с 1998 года. В этом году выставка проходит с 14 по 19 марта.</div>

</div>
```

Comment: а вопрос то в чем?

Comment: что бы текст в 3й новости быт так же как и во второй

Comment: Добавь обтекание для img float или align

Comment: оно же добавлено, или я что то не понимаю?

Comment: Чтобы сообщество могло быстрее Вам помочь, заносите код в элемент "Фрагмент кода javascript/html/css".

Comment: Возможно [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/625256/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82-%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB-%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8) Вам поможет. Дайте знать.

Comment: Ты кроме тега  <br> других тегов не знаешь?